# Changing colors to custom button

Tags: android

I have a custom button in my drawable folder.
I want to use it multiple times in my XML file, with different colors.
Is there a way to use the same custom_button but with different color?

Comment: Just Use different 9-patch images for the different colors or create multiple custom drawable definitions in xml file

Comment: As i understand from both the answers(Rachita Nanda and K_Anas), i still have to create different drawable files for different buttons.
I was just wondering, is there a way to change only the color in a specific <solid> in the drawable xml for each button i create

Answer (score 0):

Firstly create a selector xml file .Selector will let you change button image on specific states like focused or pressed .
I am giving you the sample code for selector

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ok_pressed"
          android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ok"  />

</selector>
```

Now using StateListDrawable you can assign a number of graphic images to a single Drawable and swap out the visible item by a string ID value.

```
StateListDrawable state_up = new StateListDrawable();
        state_up.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_pressed},getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_up_cyan));
        state_up.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_focused},getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_up_cyan));
        b1.setBackgroundDrawable(state_up);
```

Just use different color images as background and use the above code when you wish to change the background